# Horizontal UISwipeGestureRecognizer doesn't work for Small UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to a UIImageView located on my UIViewController and it works fine if the frame of the UIImageView is set to the screen bounds. I need the UIImageView much smaller and when I set the frame to the proper dimensions it no longer picks up the horizontal swipes. How can I get this to work on anything smaller than the full screen size ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star-Rating-Stroke.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


    imageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];  // THIS WORKS !!!
//  imageView.frame = CGRectMake(36,70,33,33);         // THIS DOESN'T !!!
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];

   // Setting the swipe direction.
   [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
   [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

   // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
   [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
   [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (IBAction) handleRightSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
    NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
}

- (IBAction) handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
    NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works when the image view is full screen, then it will work with (some) smaller frames as well. You should experiment by gradually reducing the size of the image view to see where exactly you start to have problems.

Anyway, at a very small size like the one you're using this makes perfect sense. The UISwipeGestureRecognizer class will have some internal measurement that it uses to determine if the finger has panned far enough in the specified direction for the gesture to be recognized. If your image view's frame is smaller than this (unknown) value, then the gesture will always fail.

As an alternative approach, I would suggest that you either make your own subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that acts like a swipe gesture, but requires less movement for detection. If this isn't something you're interested in doing, you could consider adding a gesture to the image view's super view and tracking the location of the touch events to determine if they happened within the image view's bounds.